# Is it possible for Cypress to add new columns between already existing columns in CSV?

Tags: typescript, csv, cypress

In my tests, I need to download CSV file and edit it, specifically I need to add three new columns between already existing columns without overwriting them, I have tried some CSV libraries but non of them is able to do that. Is it even possible to do that in Cypress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution: we can add additional columns to an existing csv in cypress and then edit its content using javascript by using **cy.readFile** and **cy.writeFile**.

1. **cy.readFile** can be used to read the CSV content.
2. convert the CSV content to JSON using javascript then add the new columns
3. then convert the result JSON back to CSV content
4. To update the file with the content of the csv result, use **cy.writeFile**.

script:

```
    const filePath = './cypress/downloads/example.csv' // path of your downloaded csv

    cy.readFile(filePath).then((csvContent) => {

    // ***** Convert CSV to JSON ***** //
    var lines = csvContent.split("\n");

    var result = [];
    var dataRow = '';
    var headers = (lines[0].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "")).split(",");

    var newColumn = ["NewColum4", "NewColumn5", "NewColumn6"] // add here the new columns

    // statement below will insert the new header column in the right most
    // can modify this statement below if you want to insert the column In between or left most
    headers = headers.concat(newColumn)

    for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {

        var obj = {};
        var currentline = (lines[i].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "")).split(",");

        for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
            if (newColumn.includes(headers[j])) { // if new column set to empty string in data rows
                dataRow = "";
            } else { // else if it is an existing column use existing data rows
                dataRow = currentline[j]
            }
            obj[headers[j]] = dataRow;
        }
        result.push(obj);
    }

    cy.log(JSON.stringify(result))


    // ***** Then Convert JSON to CSV back ***** //
    var csvResult = '';

    csvResult += headers + '\r\n';

    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        var item = result[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
            var obj = item[headers[j]];
            csvResult += obj;
            if (j < headers.length - 1) {
                csvResult += ',';
            }
        }
        csvResult += '\r\n';
    }
    cy.log(csvResult)

    cy.writeFile(filePath, csvResult) // Update CSV File
})
```

**NOTE:**

- The sample script above may not work since CSV content can vary, especially if the data rows contain a "," however you can change it to any special characters and then convert again.
- The script uses the delimiter "," but you can change it to use something else instead of a comma.
- New columns will be added in the right most with empty data rows ,
  can modify it.
- Can use Cypress Custom Command to simplify the script above: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands